# Navigation Drawer DrawerArrowStyle Click effect

Tags: android

I added navigation drawer with material design using this tutorial. http://www.nkdroid.com/2014/11/Android-Lollipop-Navigation-Drawer-Example-Using-Appcompat-21.html every thing works fine and smooth. when I click on the arrow or menu, button click effect is not showing. thanks in advance.
How can I give the selector for DrawerArrowStyle so that i can have the button effect for that.

```
    style.xml
<resources>

    <style name="myAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="spinBars">true</item>
        <item name="color">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>

</resources>


    active_main.xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <!-- activity view -->

        <include layout="@layout/main_contents" />

        <!-- navigation drawer -->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left|start"
            android:background="#fff" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:divider="#eee"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>

    toolbar.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" >

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replaced my toolbar.xml to this and it works awesome. thanks to all...:-)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```